# An aggregate function not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement

Tags: sql

```
UPDATE PSO_UltraCoatRolls  
SET TotalInSeries=
COUNT(pd.PINSerialNumber) 
FROM PINDetail pd 
WHERE pd.PINSerialNumber 
BETWEEN (SELECT pr.StratSerial FROM PSO_UltraCoatRolls pr) AND 
(SELECT pr1.EndSerial FROM PSO_UltraCoatRolls pr1)
```

Comment: Tag dbms used! (That UPDATE - FROM syntax is not ANSI SQL compliant.) Or do you perhaps want `UPDATE t SET c = (SELECT... )`?

Comment: *In general*, don't *store* data that you can *compute*. That just leads to the possibility that the stored result is no longer consistent with the base data. If you *do* need to store the computed value, if possible have the database engine do it automatically for you. If you're using e.g. [tag:sql-server], then an indexed view would seem appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the key word **SELECT** before  *Count(pd.PINSerialNumber)*